# DropDownList in conjunction with file upload in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a file upload function in my asp.net mvc application that allows users to upload an xslx file containing data that should be persisted to a database. That data can be related to one of many categories. I need to be able to discern which category the data that is coming in is supposed to be related to, so I thought that a drop down list would be perfect for the job. However, I don't know how to get at the lists selected value when the user posts the data. This is what the code for the form looks like:

```
    <form action="/Import/UploadFiles/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset id="fileImport">
        <legend>Importinställningar</legend>
        <label for="file">Importfil:</label>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
        <%= Html.DropDownList("Name", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["assignments"]) %>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Spara"/>
            <input type="button" value="Avbryt" onclick="window.location.href='/'" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Since I am dealing with a file upload scenario I don't have an action link that I can use to pass data to the controller, but rather an input with the type submit.

How should I go about reading the select value of the drop down list so that its selected value can be passed to the Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways that you can make this work.  First, add a string parameter named `Name` to your UploadFiles method.  The default binder will fill it in from the form value with the same name.  Alternatively, you can use the ValueProvider inside the controller -- if you use the same action for both rendering the view and responding to the post, for instance -- to extract the value of the parameter named `Name`.

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles( string Name )
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles()
{
     string name = this.ValueProvider.ContainsKey("Name")
                         ? this.ValueProvider[key].AttemptedValue
                         : null;

     ...
 }
```

Comment: I got stuck thinking I had to pass the value through the resulting Url. Of course this works. Thanks a bunch! Takes a little while to get used to MVC :)